# DbgHelp enumerating local variables

Tags: c, winapi, dbghelp

I'm trying to enumerate over all variables in a function using DbgHelp. The only problem I'm facing is that `SymEnumSymbols` is scoped, so it doesn't find variables inside if statements for example. I'm aware of `SymSetContext`, but that would require me to know the address range in which a scope exists. Does DbgHelp provide any way of enumerating scopes in a function? Or some other way to enumerate local variables?